# Accessing elements created on-the-fly jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework, galleria

i am using this [gallery plugin](http://galleria.aino.se/) but i can't access the elements created on-the-fly by the plugin. what can i do??

Thanks folks!!

Comment: What do you mean, "access"?  How are you trying to access the elements? What code have you used so far, and how do you know it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Galleria, you can access each DOM element using f.ex `this.get('container')` or `this.get('stage')` in the extend option.

You can also use f.ex `this.$('thumbnails')` that will return the element in a jQuery context.

Answer (score 1):

.live() is your friend but this is a plugin so it is probably not applicable.

attaching events to objects in the dom (like $('.box img').click... ) will not be attached to any new elements....

not used that plugin but perhaps there is a 'refresh' method similar to .sortable that will ensure any new element to be included has the correct event handlers attached